# Is the size of a union equal to the size of its member of the largest size?

Tags: c, unions

Some books say yes, but the following code shows it's not true

```
union
{
     int n;
     char array[5];
} u;
printf("%d %d %d", sizeof(u.n), sizeof(u.array), sizeof(u));
```

What's your opinion?

Comment: you forgot to add the output of your code

Answer (score 3):

The size of a union must satisfy two requirements:

- It must be at least as large as its largest member
- It must be a multiple of the alignment requirement of each of its members.

The latter rule is needed so that arrays work; it keeps unions properly aligned when placed one after the other in memory.

So, if the largest element is five bytes but some element requires four-byte alignment, the union size must be a multiple of four bytes greater than or equal to five bytes. Eight bytes satisfies this.

Most C implementations use the smallest size that obeys these two rules.

Comment: Your second requirement `It must be a multiple of the alignment requirement of each of its members.` is incorrect, I'm afraid.

Comment: @KenY-N: Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.2.1 14, ”Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation-defined manner appropriate to its type.” Per 3.2 1, alignment is a requirement that objects of a particular type be located at addresses that are particular multiples of a bytes address. Per 6.2.5 20, array elements are contiguously allocated. Mathematically, the only way an array of union objects can satisfy all of these requirements is if the union size is a multiple of the alignment requirement of each of its members.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Cx0 standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.1.html#1425) it says:

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members

So, you cannot rely on the size being equal to the size of the largest member. Whether it is on not depends on the compiler implementation, flags used, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The union in this case is aligned to 4 bytes on 32 bit machine(or 8 bytes on 64 bit machines) so it will look in memory as something like this:

```
11 11 11 11
11 XX XX XX
   ^   ^  ^
   3 padded bytes
```

So extra three bytes are added for alignment, that what make the size 8. If you want to change this behavior you need to pack it on 1 byte:

```
#pragma pack(1)
union
{
     int n;
     char array[5];
} u;
#pragma pack()
```

now the size of the union is exactly 5 and will look like:

```
11 11 11 11
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler usually determines the size based on the alignment requirements. In your case the size of largest member is 5 and aligning it makes it 8. This is needed because you may declare an array of this union type.

Answer (score 1):

The standard only guarantee that the size of a `union` is sufficient for the largest member, i.e, not necessarily the same size.

> ### C11 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> The size of a `union` is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at
>   most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a `union` object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield,
>   then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

---

When I run your example on my machine, the output is `4 5 8`, probably the size of the `union` is padded to be multiples of a machine word, just like `struct`.

Comment: Neither union nor struct need to be aligned to a machine word as a general rule. They need to be aligned for the strictest alignment of any of their members.